# How do I reset my audio settings to default?

Tags: sound, alsa, jack

I have been using Ubuntu Studio for about 2 years and I love it. Everything has been working fine until recently. I was using Jack for most things, but then I discovered I didn't really need it so I just stopped opening QJackctl and using the default audio settings, Alsa I guess. I've been doing this for over 6 months with no issues.

I went on vacation last week. Before I went, my sound was working fine. I could edit sound, play videos, and play games, all with great sound. I didn't even do an update just before I left. When I returned, I turned on the computer, and now I get very distorted warbled sound when playing games and also watching videos. It's so odd because I haven't done anything to change audio.

I did update and upgrade this week just in case that would fix it but it does not.

I've been poling around the audio settings and now it seems I have disabled audio entirely. I did open qJackCtl and went into the settings to see if I could make it work with Jack again, but it seems I made it worse. I wonder if there is a way to reset it to the default audio settings?

I don't even know where to begin to fix this. I do think I want to move to Pipewire when Ubuntu Studio 22.04 releases. Maybe I should try the setup now?

I am on a custom built desktop, Intel i7, Nvidia 2060 Super, 32G ram, with Mackie studio monitors, and I use a Focusrite Scarlett Solo audio input. This setup has worked flawlessly for nearly 2 years. I can't think of anything I changed recently that would cause this issue.

Where might I even start troubleshooting?

Comment: Hello. If you upgrade to a release that does not exist yet you will not get support on this site till after it does. Just something to think about.

Comment: Thanks for Pipewire advert. I had this twice today.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I am currently on Ubuntu Studio 21.10. I went ahead and disabled PA and installed and enabled Pipewire and it's all working perfectly. Everywhere else that I asked, people said, just upgrade to Pipewire and don't bother trying to troubleshoot. I did, and it works great.